# Local Storage/Session Storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, local-storage

My Html file is as follows:

```
<h2>Welcome User!!!</h2>
<form class="container" action="/product">
    <div>
        <label for="mail"><b>Email-ID: [(ngModel)]</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter mail ID" [(ngModel)]="mail" name="mail" required>
        <label for="psw"><b>Phone Number</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" [(ngModel)]="mail" name="phoneNumber" required>

        <button (click)="myFunc()">NEXT</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Typescript file is as follows:

```
   import { Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MyProductPageComponent } from '../my-product-page/my-product-page.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-home-page',
  templateUrl: './my-home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-home-page.component.css']
})

export class MyHomePageComponent implements OnInit {
  phoneNumber = "";
  mailID = "";

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  myFunc() {
    localStorage.setItem("phoneNumber", this.phoneNumber);
    localStorage.setItem("mail", this.mailID);
    this.router.navigate(['/products']);
  }
}

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'MyProductPageComponent', component: MyProductPageComponent },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

I want to fetch Phone number and Mail ID entered in form and save that in Local Storage. And redirect to the next page. Please help.
Am getting this error: Declaration expected.

Comment: You don't have `phoneNumber` and `mailID` variables inside your component.

Comment: I tried define them in class MyHomePageComponent. But it's throwing a different error altogether. Where it should be defined.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use ngmodel to bind the value with input control and same you can access in your component.

```js
<h2>Welcome User!!!</h2>
<form class="container" action="/product">
    <div>
        <label for="mail"><b>Email-ID: </b></label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="mailID" placeholder="Enter mail ID" name="mail" required>
        <label for="psw"><b>Phone Number</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="phoneNumber" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" required>

        <button (click)="myFunc()">NEXT</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Declaration Expected error in .ts file. Is still pending

Comment: yes you need to create same variable which you have provided in the ngmodel in .ts file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add variables to phone/mail in your **.ts** components
2. Use `this` to variables in `myFunc()` to get the value of the variables
3. Use `ngModel` to bind the variables with the input of the user (set `ngModel` on the input not label).
4. Use `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';` in the `app.module` and NOT in your component

[see working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qrrex9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<h2>Welcome User!!!</h2>
<form class="container" action="/product">
    <div>
        <label for="mail"><b>Email-ID:</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter mail ID"  [(ngModel)]="mail" name="mail" required>
        <label for="psw"><b>Phone Number</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required>

        <button (click)="myFunc()">NEXT</button>
    </div>
</form>


  phoneNumber = "";
  mailID = "";
  myFunc() {
    localStorage.setItem("phoneNumber", this.phoneNumber);
    localStorage.setItem("mail", this.mailID);
  }
```

Comment: Failed to compile.

src/app/my-home-page/my-home-page.component.ts:36:3 - error TS1146: Declaration expected.

36 })

Comment: First two error got solved. Third one still remaining.

Comment: please take a look at the example (link) that I attached and tell me if you do it the same (can u tell me the exact  error )

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-first-app';
}

Comment: Where we should provide the Routing in general?

Comment: routing declare in `app.module` (in case you have one module) and you can use navigate in each component you want

Answer (score 1):

```
        const routes: Routes = [
          { path: 'MyProductPageComponent', component: MyProductPageComponent },
        ]
        The path variable should not have a component  and you are using router.navigate('/products') 
       const routes: Routes = [
          { path: 'products', component: MyProductPageComponent },
        ]
These variables which are used in the ts should bind with the ngModel used in the template 
phoneNumber = "";
mailID = "";

<h2>Welcome User!!!</h2>
<form class="container" action="/product">
    <div>
        <label for="mail"><b>Email-ID: </b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter mail ID" [(ngModel)]="mailID" name="mail" required>
        <label for="psw"><b>Phone Number</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" required>

        <button (click)="myFunc()">NEXT</button>
    </div>
</form>
```